# How to update the xpath as per the data passed through feature file

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I have a scenario where i need to click on the date. Date need to be send from the feature file.
xpath is as below.

```
//table[@class="mat-calendar-table"]/tbody/tr/td[@aria-label="January 1, 2019"].
```

Feature file as below

```
 Scenario: Protractor date pickers Test"
    Given Go to title page
    Then The title must be "Datepicker | Angular Material"
    When enter the date "January 6, 2019"
```

Please let me know how to pass the date from feature file to xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { Given, Then, When } from "cucumber";

// if using async/await
When(/^enter the date "(.*)"$/, async(date) => {
  var util = require('util');
  var xpath = '/table[@class="mat-calendar-table"]/tbody/tr/td[@aria-label="%s"]'

  return await element(by.xpath(util.format(xpath, date))).sendKeys(date);
});

// not using async await
When(/^enter the date "(.*)"$/, (date) => {
  var util = require('util');
  var xpath = '/table[@class="mat-calendar-table"]/tbody/tr/td[@aria-label="%s"]'

  return element(by.xpath(util.format(xpath, date))).sendKeys(date);
});
```